# Put results of a Get request from axios to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, get

I don't understand a very simple task, I made a request from a API with axios in react.
If I console log the res.data, is like 170 result of single objects on my console.

I need to convert all these result in a single array of objects.

It's a basic task but I don't understand how to do it.

The application is a Trello Clone.

I have a variable called board that has all the data and with this list request, I grab all the column the the trello and append to ListObjects [] in newBoardData (it's a clone of board)

Here is my code:

```
//Get Request

const getList = async (id) => {
  try {
  return await axios.get(`${ENDPOINT}/lists/${id}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};



  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  // Use Effect for grab the data with the listId 

  useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await (getList(listId));
          //Loading up the listObjects
           const oldList = board.board.listObjects
           const newList = []
          const payload = res.data;
           //Adding all the old values to the new list (except for the current payload id)
          for(let obj of oldList){
          if(obj._id !== payload._id) newList.push(obj)
           } 
             //Adding the current payload id
           newList.push(payload)  
          const data = {
            ...board,
            board: {...board.board, listObjects: newList}
          };
          setList(res.data);

          // Here I put the data objects with the new ListObjects Array
          setBoardNew(data);

          setLoading(false);
      })();
  }, []);
```

Here is the console log of the get request res.data:

[console.log of res.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzaEW.png)

here is the board object:

[board object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZeAl.png)

You can saw that there is a spam of result with the current res.data in ListObjects

I'think it make a request for every card in every list.

thank you very much!

UPDATE:

I will explain how the app works:

I have a file called Board.js, where I make this call (in the console log I have two call if I have two columns):

```
    try {
    return await axios.get(`${ENDPOINT}/boards/${id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await (getUserBoard(match.params.id));
          if (res) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['boardId'] = match.params.id;
            
          } else {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['boardId'];
          }
          
          const payload = { ...res.data, listObjects: [], cardObjects: [] };
          const data = {
            ...state,
            board: { ...state.board, ...payload },
          };
          setBoardData(data);
          setLoading(false);
      })();
  }, []);
```

Then I send the props data to the file List.js

```
 {board.board.lists.map((listId, index) => (
               
                  <List key={listId} listId={listId} index={index} board={board} />
```

The list file send the data to
card.js

```
 {list.cards.map((cardId, index) => (
                    <Card key={cardId} cardId={cardId} list={list} index={index} board={boardNew} />
```

The logic is: There is the board(board.js), in the board there are the lists (column)(list.js) in the lists there are the cards (card.js)

I hope it's more clear.

Comment: I believe the issue you're having is with the useEffect hook. I see that it will only run once on component mount. If you're seeing it 170 times, it looks like this code is in each card hence being mounted 170 times. The code you posted here doesn't show enough to help you what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

simple use this approach to add your new id value into the array state.

```
this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, 'new value'] }) //simple value
this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, ...[1,2,3] ] }) //another array
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried but it print one array for every call with inside one data ( the current)

I have added this in my UseEffect


` setMyArray({ myArray: [...myArray, res.data] }) `